# Does the MTASC compiler also compile AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mtasc

Looks like [MTASC](http://www.mtasc.org/) is for AS2. Does it also compile AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, you can use `mxmlc` to compile AS3.

[Download the Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4) (mxmlc is included)

[Read here](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/) for a nice tutorial using `mxmlc` to compile AS3.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually going to use sprouts

Comment: ... that shouldn't stop you using `mxmlc`

Comment: i am pretty sure sprouts uses MTASC for AS2 and mxmlc for AS3 :)

Comment: That's what I am saying... :)

Answer (score 0):

Same guy who wrote **MTASC** wrote [**Haxe**](http://haxe.org/doc/intro) it compiles to many languages including AS1, AS3, JavaScript and PHP